# Why is this wiremock setup based on wireMockConfig not working?

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Why is this wiremock setup based on wireMockConfig not working?

```
package com.example.wiremockjunitstandalone;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.ok;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.admin.model.ListStubMappingsResult;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

@DirtiesContext
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = {WiremockJunitStandaloneApplication.class})
public class WireMockStubbing {

  public static WireMockServer wireMockServer;

  @BeforeAll
  public static  void setUp() {
    // Start WireMock server with the desired hostname and port
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(9999).bindAddress("localhost"));
    wireMockServer.start();
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void tearDown() {
    // Stop WireMock server after all tests are done
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }

  @Test
  @SneakyThrows
  void onlyPath_localhost() {

    //ignore below
    ListStubMappingsResult stubslist = WireMock.listAllStubMappings();
    System.err.println("stubslist.getMappings().size(): " + stubslist.getMappings().size());
    System.err.println("stubslist.getMappings(): " + stubslist.getMappings());

    HttpRequest request;
    HttpResponse<String> response;

    stubFor(get("/get").willReturn(ok("Hello")));

    request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(new URI("http://localhost:9999/get"))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .GET()
        .build();
    response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    Assertions.assertEquals("Hello", response.body());

  }
```

I am facing below error -

> Connect to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1,
> localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
> wiremock.org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect
> to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1,
> localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Why is port 8080 being considered, when port 9999 is explicitly configured. I checked by debuging the port of 9999 is what is taken in options.. so still why 8080 is coming in between.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the static DSL and change the port number you have to tell the client part which port you're using by calling `WireMock.configureFor(wireMockServer.port())`. You need to do this after `start()` and before any calls to `stubFor(...)` etc.